# Improve vs Improve on

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I just want to confirm the usages of the phrasal verb "improve on" and the word "improve". My understanding is that one *improves* his skills, abilities and one *improves on* results, a numbers. Am I right? or both are interchangeable?

1. > I will need to ***improve on*** my English.
2. > I will need to ***improve*** my English.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct, but your examples hit upon a special case where "my English" is both a result, something visible and measurable, and an ability or facet of yourself. Here, either could be used, though I would personally use 2.

Answer (score 3):

I shan't go into detail about the grammar since I'm not very knowledgeable about that,but as I understand it the two have a slightly different connotation.

***To improve*** means *"to make the original instance better"* where ***to improve on*** means *"creating a new instance which is similar to the original, but better"*.

For example, if I have a car and I *improve* it, I would do so by replacing some of the parts for instance.

If I'm *improving on* the car however, I would be building a new car, similar in many ways to the original car, but this time I'm using different parts to make it better than the original.

In other words, to **improve** modifies the original while to **improve on** leaves the original intact.

This difference is confirmed by the Oxford dictionary [entry found here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/improve):

> Definition of improve in English:
>   verb
>
> 1 Make or become better:
>   [WITH OBJECT]: efforts to improve relations between the countries
>   (as adjective improved) an improved design
>
> 1.2 [NO OBJECT] (improve on/upon) Achieve or produce something better than:
>   they are trying to improve on the tired old style

Answer (score 1):

As you stated that 'improve' is a verb and 'improve on' is a phrasal verb. While both are *nearly* close, here is the minute difference I can think of.

TheFreeDictionaries states:

> improve: *to make or become better in quality*

but...

> improve (intr; usually followed by ***on*** or upon) to achieve a better standard or quality ***in comparison (with)***

The example follows:

> *to improve on last year's crop.*

As I see a few more examples on the dictionaries, I notice that 'improve on' comes with comparing it with previous state. Said that, if you can precisely measure something or if something is *tangible*, you *improve on* it.

In other words, you ***improve on*** the last year's sales figures.

If you are not peculiar to **compare** your English and *simply* want to improve it, dropping *'on'* is okay.

But in the case, say, you *know* English but now you want to ***improve on English grammar***. This means you are now comparing English (in general) with improved English with better grammar.

Comment: You were going to get my upvote, until the last paragraph. "your English grammar" is not a previous state, therefore you can't improve *on* it.